# FFMpeg video creation from png not all images used

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to turn png files into a video using ffmpeg.  I am getting videos but the ordering is all wrong.

My directory looks like this:

```
*otherstuff..not pngs*
file_01.png
file_02.png
...
file_69.png
```

I want this to create a movie, starting with file_1.png and ending with file_69.png.

I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -start_number 01 -i file_%02d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p outN1.mp4
```

Which I got from 
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images
with a minor adjustment to the start number.

I have tried various other things such as glob patterns

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

And the order is right, but not all the images are there.  To be precise, the last 4 images are not present.  Why would this be?

*********** EDIT ****************

The following hack does work...

```
cp file_69.png file_70.png
...
cp file_69.png file_75.png
```

And then run the above command.  And then I see the last images.  This is a rather disappointing work around.

Comment: Please show the full, uncut command line output from the ffmpeg conversion

Comment: How are you determining the frames as "not present"?

Comment: @dstob: I literally counted the number of frames in the video file.  Each frame was different, so the frames were easily countable.

Comment: @Jonathan Gallagher: Ran your first command on a group of my own pngs and everything worked except it was 69 pngs spread over 5:40, not 5:45. First two frames were duplicates so 1 was dropped. Update ffmpeg. Increase your verbosity and find out what x264 is doing with those last frames.